# HTTPService & MySQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, post, httpservice

I can't seem to post needed information to my database, here's what I've got:

```
<mx:HTTPService id="someService" url="http://name.domain/postPHP.php" method="POST">
    <s:request xmlns="">
            <name>{name.text}</name>
            <score>{score.text}</score>
    </s:request>
</mx:HTTPService>
```

And of course a button to send();

Php as follows:

```
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n;

$connections = ...;
mysql_select_db("...");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$score = $_POST['score'];

$query = "INSERT INTO hs (name, score) VALUES ('$name', '$score')"; 
mysql_query($query);
```

So what is wrong? Why ain't it adding the information to my database?

Thanks, Yan

Comment: Your SQL is malformed. What errors did it return?

Comment: @user257493: Where do you see a syntax error in the INSERT statement?  I don't...

Comment: Are you missing a close-quote on the `<?xml` line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing a " at the end of the first line:

```
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n";

$connections = ...;
mysql_select_db("...");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$score = $_POST['score'];

$query = "INSERT INTO hs (name, score) VALUES ('$name', '$score')"; 
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: lolcats... double quotes enclose the string in many of the cases... bad bad bad, but I won't downvote you if you fix it.

Comment: I'm assuming it's all one big echo

Answer (score 0):

In these simple examples, I *guess* it is ok to use raw sql directly to the mysql function libraries...

However, it's so simple to use PDO, and not deal with all the security BS, lack of portability, etc..

Here is how you use a [prepared statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Just do it that way, and avoid having to learn about mysql_real_escape_string and all the rest of the crap, then having to relearn PDO...

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't accept @grossvogel comment as an answer, but that is in fact correct, all was missing is that close-quote.. Many thanks to all!

```
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n";

$connections = ...;
mysql_select_db("...");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$score = $_POST['score'];

$query = "INSERT INTO hs (name, score) VALUES ('$name', '$score')"; 
mysql_query($query);
```